# GTM: pageview not firing in product page section even when all pages trigger

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm inspecting the tags implementation for a company.

1) I'm finding it strange that the PageView tag implemented with GTM fires in the home page, but not in the product page.

For example, in this laptop producto page:

[https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/laptop-asus-x507ub-br161t-core-i5-156-1tb-4gb-x507ub-br161t?cm_cr=No+Campaign-*-Web+Activity-*-No+Name-_-Widget_CatalogEntryRecommendation_701_3074457345618283237-_-Laptop+Asus+X507UB-BR161T+15.6%22+Core+i5+7ma+Generaci%C3%B3n+1TB+4GB+NVIDIA+2GB-productImageLink](https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/laptop-asus-x507ub-br161t-core-i5-156-1tb-4gb-x507ub-br161t?cm_cr=No+Campaign-_-Web+Activity-_-No+Name-_-Widget_CatalogEntryRecommendation_701_3074457345618283237-_-Laptop+Asus+X507UB-BR161T+15.6%22+Core+i5+7ma+Generaci%C3%B3n+1TB+4GB+NVIDIA+2GB-productImageLink)

Even provided that this tag is supposed to fire on all pages.

2) Also I'm noticing that my clicks listeners are not working in this section also. But work in other sections of the page. May it be the gtm.click or the gtm.linkClick

3) The GTM container is instaled in the code, as this image shows:

[image]

What could be preventing the PageView Tag to fire and the click listeners to work?

**My PageView TAG:**

[image]

***The All Pages trigger is the default one.***

**This is my container preview**:

[https://www.googletagmanager.com/start_preview/gtm?uiv2&id=GTM-5VMNG2H&gtm_auth=T6D4je8bCBlHxyaINtja3Q&gtm_preview=env-5&gtm_debug=x&url=https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/laptop-asus-x507ub-br161t-core-i5-156-1tb-4gb-x507ub-br161t?cm_cr=No+Campaign-*-Web+Activity-*-No+Name-_-Widget_CatalogEntryRecommendation_701_3074457345618283237-_-Laptop+Asus+X507UB-BR161T+15.6%22+Core+i5+7ma+Generaci%C3%B3n+1TB+4GB+NVIDIA+2GB-productImageLink](https://www.googletagmanager.com/start_preview/gtm?uiv2&id=GTM-5VMNG2H&gtm_auth=T6D4je8bCBlHxyaINtja3Q&gtm_preview=env-5&gtm_debug=x&url=https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/laptop-asus-x507ub-br161t-core-i5-156-1tb-4gb-x507ub-br161t?cm_cr=No+Campaign-_-Web+Activity-_-No+Name-_-Widget_CatalogEntryRecommendation_701_3074457345618283237-_-Laptop+Asus+X507UB-BR161T+15.6%22+Core+i5+7ma+Generaci%C3%B3n+1TB+4GB+NVIDIA+2GB-productImageLink)

Comment: Did you place your part of gtm code as high in <head> section? if not try loading the gtm scripts  higher to other <scripts>. May be some other scripts overrides GTM scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check how the dataLayer is being implemented.  I ran into an issue where my Page View tag/All Pages trigger was broken because I had initialized the dataLayer after the gtm code snippet.